# Where is the iPhone's Date & Time getting its time zone list

Tags: iphone, xcode, timezone

I can get a list of time zones with `[NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]`, but that only gives the time zone IDs which include one or two cities in each time zone.

The Date & Time settings has a great list of cities and I have seen a few other apps that have the same if not similar lookup lists.

Where do these lists come from?

I do need to relate a picked city to its time zone like Date & Time does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only 2? On 3.1 the `[NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]` returns an array of 401 elements, and there are much less than 200 timezones on the Earth.

I'm pretty sure "other apps" use `+knownTimeZoneNames` as well, since this is the only public method returning such list. Please make sure your code is correct, though.

---

Settings.app uses the **private** [CPCity](http://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/AppSupport/CPCity.h) API from the **private** AppSupport.framework. It does have San Francisco, but it's private.

You need to create your own database (the data can be copied from `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/all_cities_adj.plist`).

Comment: knowTimeZoneNames does not have the same list as the other lists. For example in California the only city in the knownTimeZoneNames list is America/Los Angeles. You will not find any other city, however, if you go to Date & Time you will find a host of cities, like San Francisco, San Jose, Sacramento, etc.

Comment: Each time zone has multiple cites, but from different locales. For example in the Pacific time zone the only US city I can find is Los Angeles, however you will find Vancouver which I believe is Vancouver BC. This I think accounts for the disparity between the number of actual time zones in the world and the number of cities in the list.

Comment: Kenny, Thanks that plist is going to be what I am looking for. 

Do you know anything about the list? It is a list of arrays that contain...

item 0 = latitude
item 1 = longitude
item 2 = ?? time zone??
item 3 = ?? time zone id ???
item 4 = country abbreviation
item 5 = city
item 6 = country

Any idea what item 2 is? it shows 1 for Honolulu and it should be -10. Also for all of the US cities it uses US/Eastern, US/Pacific, etc. As I understand it these are not valid time zone IDs. US/Pacific should be America/Los Angeles.

No problem, I can us Lat/Long to get time zone.

thanks again,
John

Comment: @johnbdh: Open the file with a text editor. 'TimeZoneIndex 0-27 used to show timezone "band"'. Probably not very usable. You have to match field 4 "TimeZone file" with the time zone name you get from NSTimeZone it seems. Also this list has only 211 entries, whereas I got some 400 entries from the public API. But this list contains a lot of cities not on the other list... Have to look into this more. Will probably combine the lists. But thanks for asking this question, I had also noticed that there were more cities in the Settings app than I could get from the API.

Comment: A few things i have learned so far in this exercise...

1. all_cities_adj.plist has 193 cities
2. knownTimeZoneNames returns 405
3. if you combine the 2 without duplicates you get 465
4. the time zone list in Date & Time preferences still has cities non existent in the above 2 lists such as San Jose, Pitsburgh.
5. knownTimeZoneNames is not the same list used by timeZoneWithName. You can pass timeZoneWithName US/Eastern and get the correct time zone, but US/Eastern does not appear in the list returned by knownTimeZoneNames.

This has been an interesting exercise. thanks to all who helped.
John

Comment: Check out `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/world.geokit`.

Comment: @rid /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/world.g‌​eokit is a 47.7mb file, what should I do with it?

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is commonly referred to as the Olson database. See for instance [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). The public domain [Zone.tab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone.tab) file contains all of the timezones. You can find a zones.tab file in the zoneinfo directory of the [libical](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeassociation/) distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I know it might be a late answer, but just in case someone else stumbles on it like I did the other day. I just open sourced a library that does exactly this. It is available as a CocoaPod and you can find it here:

https://github.com/gligorkot/TimeZonePicker

Also, thanks for all the replies above, they helped me in finding the correct cities database that is used for the Settings app.