# Can i get the timezone as we get the clock application in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, timezone

Can we get the timezone similar to what is shown in the clock application?  I am getting timezone array like this:

```
NSDictionary *TimeZoneArray = [NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary];
```

Through this I am getting array for continent, now I am getting data like:  `Asia/Kabul,Asia/Muscat,Asia/Kuala_Lumpur,Asia/Hong_Kong` but I want data something like this: 
`Asia/India/Delhi, Asia/India/Kolkata,Asia/India/Mumbai`.

Hope I am clear with my question.

What I want is name of continent with country name and then city name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible solution is
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/all_cities_adj.plist file We can get data from that plist.

Source is 
[Where is the iPhone's Date & Time getting its time zone list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985853/where-is-the-iphones-date-time-getting-its-time-zone-list)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
NSLog(@"Timezone is %@", [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone].name);
```

You'll need to parse the response string but that should be fairly trivial.

Answer (score 0):

here is the new one:

```
/System/Library/PreferencePanes/DateAndTime.prefPane/Contents/Resources/TimeZone.prefPane/Contents/Resources/all_cities_adj.plist
```